# Usage of "id" in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, dynamic

I have a function that returns "id". Does this include a return of void? (as in nothing) Or does "id" require some kind of object/variable?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7987060/objective-c-the-meaning-of-id

Comment: @Mk12 Not really. I am not asking about what id is I am asking about a specific type of usage for it.

Comment: You are asking if `id` can also be considered as `void`, and by definition it can't. By the way you could have very easily tested this for yourself by reading the warnings that appear when you return nothing from a method with a return type of `id`.

Comment: and from apple https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Objective-C, `id` is a keyword that represents an untyped object pointer. It's kinda like void*, the untyped pointer, but it adds the restriction that the pointer must point to some sort of Objective-C object.

Answer (score 1):

`id` is a general data type that can wrap most objects. If you can, you usually want to opt for coding specific data types, but if the situation (in a method for example) can use a wide range of data types, `id` is used.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208303/using-id-in-objective-c) Stackoverflow post should help to explain what it is and when to use it. A simple Google search will also turn up information.

Answer (score 1):

In Objective C, `id` means `object of any type`, akin to `void*` in C/C++. You can return `nil` for from a function returning `id` to indicate that you do not want to return anything in particular.

Answer (score 1):

'id' is a pointer to an instance of an Objective-C class. So your method can return a pointer to an instance, or 'nil' (a zero pointer).