# Why does calling a property on NSObject pointer gives build errors?

Tags: objective-c

I have an `NSMutableArray` which returns me some object.
The object which I added had properties name,age.

now when I use these properties on the Object returned (`obj.name` or `obj.age` ),
Compiler says, no such member, use (`->`) instead of (`.`)

I understand that NSObject wont have these members and hence it wont understand the property.

But If i use setters, and getters as method (`[obj name]` or `[obj age]`) syntax instead of this properties, I dont get any errors.

But using property means calling a setter or getter only ?
ad Objective C is suppose to be dynamic language, right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right - dot syntax is not supported in such case.

You need to cast a pointer to the actual class:

```
((MyObject*)[array objectAtIndex: 0]).name = @"Bill";
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you cast the returned object to your object type (`MyObject`)?

You should do something like:

```
((MyObject*)[mutableArray objectAtIndex:0]).age = 20;
```

The reason you're not getting any errors when using `[[mutableArray objectAtIndex:0] name]` syntax is that you're calling a method on the returned object (which is of type `id`), and `id` s tend to not choke in the compile-time if you call a (yet) non-existant method on them. At the run-time, `[mutableArray objectAtIndex:0]` *might* resolve to type `MyObject` an in that case, the message `[obj name]` has a proper implementation (`IMP`). If it doesn't resolve to `MyObject`, your app will crash.

And note that the reason you're not even getting a compile-time warning is that Xcode knows that there is at least 1 class in your codebase that implements the method `name`, and it trusts you with calling this method *only* on instances of that class. if you do something like `((MyObject*)[mutableArray objectAtIndex:0]).ageeeeee = 20;`, it'll give you a warning as there's a very good chance that it'll crash (no class in your app implements the method `ageeeeee` *statically*).

The type `id` does not have a property `name`, and that's why you can't use dot syntax.

Actually, this incident shows perfectly why ObjC is called a dynamic language!

Comment: Thats fine. but the dot syntax is suppose to represent a call to setter or getter method. so shouldn't it work the way as a method call whether or not it existed ?
anyways.. thanks for the clarification :)

Comment: What if the property is supposed to be read only? Unless the compiler knows exactly which class/property you are talking about, it can't know whether you should be allowed to use it (at least in the case where you want to set the value).

Comment: @UIAdam: Nice point but if the property is readonly then, setter wont be generated, and i should get an "unrecognized selector sent to object exception" at runtime.

Comment: @UIAdam: The compiler handles those cases properly. If you have only one other class `MyObject` with a `readonly` property of age, method calls such as `[[array objAtIndex:0] setAge:100];` will result in a warning too. If there are multiple classes with `age` properties and at least one of them is `readwrite`, then it won't produce any warnings.

Comment: @AmoghTalpallikar It's rather complicated, but I think http://stackoverflow.com/a/1208421/347353 answers this question very well.